# Spring-Security Spring-LDAP bind with Active Directory using sAMAccountName attribute

Tags: spring, active-directory, ldap, spring-security

I have set up authentication against LDAP/AD and it is working fine. But now I wonder if it is possible to bind against Active Directory using the `sAMAccountNAme` attribute in the `userDNPattern`?

Since some AD configuration prevents unauthenticated users to search, and I can't ask for a user in order to configure the context bean, I can't define a `org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch` bean like:

```
<bean id="userSearch"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value></value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>(sAMAccountName={0})</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    <property name="searchSubtree">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Which would be enough.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Spring Security 3.1, It has built-in AD support.

Comment: That would be the nice and clean solution, but I cannot upgrade (not in my hand to do it). But I already did "add the code from last release that integrate the AD". Thank you.